# How to reset setValues in react-hook-form version 7?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I have form some prefilled values from api and i set them with
`setValues('input-field-name','value-got-from-api')` and when a i use reset method of react-hook-form it resets the newly added data but it does not reset the whole data in fields. For example. if a input fields value with setValue previously is `123` and if i typed `123abc` it resets the `abc` part and sets the fields to `12345`. But i wanted to reset to null or blank form.

The direct question will be , how can i reset the form fields either by using plain js or using react-hook-form ?

PS: i tried `reset()` method from rect-hook-form and plain js reset `document.getElementById('myform').reset();` but noting works.

Comment: I just reread you question again. Can you reproduce the problem in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-reset-v7-forked-0j5np?file=/src/index.js)?

Comment: ok let me do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`reset`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset) method returned from `useForm` hook.

```
export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {};

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("firstName", { required: true })} />
      <input {...register("lastName")} />
      <input type="button" onClick={() => {
        reset({
          firstName: "default value",
        }, {
          keepErrors: true, 
          keepDirty: true,
          keepIsSubmitted: false,
          keepTouched: false,
          keepIsValid: false,
          keepSubmitCount: false,
        });
      }} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: That above reset method works only for newly typed text ,  it does not reset previously populated values

Comment: @owlz How did the value get populated before? are you using `defaultValues` or sth else? Can you show me your form code?

Comment: for me defaultValues did not worked so i used setValues from react-hook-form

Comment: @owlz `reset` should always work regardless of how you set the input component before. Have a look at the CodesandBox I gave you earlier, the input is provided with `defaultValue` and is updated with `setValue`, and can be reset successfully after that.

Comment: ok, let me try again.